# About CSS moved icon to the left

Tags: css

```css
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #F7FAFE;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
}
.panel-default {
    padding: 10px;
    border-color: #ddd
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
.mostPopular {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mostPopular .headText h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-width: 275px;
    color: #27ae60;
}
.headText {
        text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.headText h2 {
    color: #27ae60;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mostPopular #pop {
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
.mostPopular p {
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, 'Helvetica Condensed Bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #929292;
    color: #768696;
    padding: 12px 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.mostPopular li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    padding: 7px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.mostPopular li .index {
    color: #4e5daf;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 25px;
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, "Helvetica Condensed Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.mostPopular li a {
    text-align: left;
    color: #505d69;
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, 'Helvetica Condensed Bold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 235px;
}

.mostPopular li .count {
    width: 40px;
    color: #4e5daf;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, "Helvetica Condensed Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.headLine {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #83b755, 0 -2px 0 #4b8424;
    background: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #3c81de;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.mostPopular #pop {
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
.mostPopular li .index {
    color: #4e5daf;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 25px;
    font-family: franklin-gothic-urw-cond, "Helvetica Condensed Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.thumbnaidl {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #27ae60;
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
    margin-top: -25.7px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.t11img {
    width: 23px;
    position:relative;
    left: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="mostPopular">
        <div class="headText"><h3>Most Popular Free SEO Tools</h3>    </div>
        <div id="pop">
            <p class="dlLastWeek">Business SEO Tools</p>
            <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none;">
<li>
<span class="index">1.</span> <a class="storyTitle" href="link"><span class="OneLinkNoTx">Worth Your Site</span>
<span class="count"><div style="background: #f39c12;" class="thumbnaidl">
<img alt="Worth Your Site" src="https://www.businessseotools.com/theme/default/icons/open_check.png" class="t11img">
</a> </div></span>
</li>
<li>
```

Hello Guy's i have a small problem in my website 
in my laptop looking good without any problem like you see in this screenshot 
[looks great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcSEl.jpg)

it's looking good right ? 
but when i see from a phone or tablet it's not appear clean like see ,
look at here
[see how it's looks tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27RqQ.jpg)

and this 
[see how it's looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg5ew.jpg)

thank you i need help guy's 
my regards

Comment: you need to provide your code as minimal reproducable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to get an answer

Comment: Adding a `margin-left: auto` to your icon should do the job.

Comment: here the code 
https://www.scribd.com/document/442032521/Example

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! To help you, we need to see your code _in the question_. External links can break, and other things can go wrong. Please gather the relevant code and post it here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

So if I understand it clearly, you want 2nd image to look like 3rd image, right?

To make it more like the 3rd image, you can use the `max-width` property on the container element you're using for this list.

So something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) { // When screen is at tablet height (for example)

    your-container-element {
        max-width: 400px; // This can be relative as well with %, rem, em
    }
}
```

This should force the width of your container to not get too wide.

For icons/images, if you are using floats, you can use `float: right` to push them towards the edge.

If you are using flexbox, there are various possible solutions and this answe will get too long without code samples, so I would suggest you to check this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hello my friend thank you for your respond , i want all to looks like the first picture ! and thanks again

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/442032521/Example here my friend